# How can I install Android PlayStore application from another application programmatically?

Tags: java, android, apk

I am new to creating android application and I am working on project where I need to download and install application from Android Playstore and install without user input. The only solution i could find is to launch market app and then click install button manually. But I want to install automatically. Is there any better way?

Comment: Sorry buddy I don't think it works that way, one can't simply install app without providing approp permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Installation of apps without user input isn't possible, but you can ask user to install it by following intent:

`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(GOOGLE_PLAY_APP_URL));
startActivity(intent);`

And for check if app is already installed you can use something like this:

```
public static boolean isInstalled(Context context, String packageName) {
        PackageManager pkgManager = context.getPackageManager();
        Intent launchIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        launchIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = pkgManager.queryIntentActivities(launchIntent, 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < resInfo.size(); i++) {
            ResolveInfo ri = resInfo.get(i);
            String pkgName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
            if (pkgName.contains(packageName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to download application using GOOGLE_PLAY_APP_URL to internal memory or sdcard and then install via another intent?